# What kind of c++ runtime redistributable packages should I install?

Tags: c++, windows

I want to include VC 8.0 runtime redistributable packages into my app installer. What kind of C++ runtime redistributable packages should I install on the client's computer?

My app is in 32-bit mode. If the OS is 64-bit, should I install x86 or x64 version?

I guess I should install x64, because my app would call a wrapper of x64 version, but I'm not sure.

Comment: "*my app is in 32-bit mode, if the os is 64-bit, should I install x86 or x64 version ?*" The x86 redist; the x64 redist can only be used by 64-bit apps on 64-bit OSs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 32 bit->64 bit wrapping is normally done only for system libraries, and it's done by the operating system, so that any 32 bit user-mode component can run unchanged.

For this reason you just have to provide 32 bit versions of user-mode libraries that your program uses, including the standard library dlls (i.e. the VC++ redist).